# How to pass integer as pointer using interface{} to function

Tags: pointers, go, interface

I thought this is a simple thing to do, but I was wrong. I can't pass `integer` as pointer to function using `interface{}`.

Example:

```
var test int
someChange(&test)
fmt.Printf("after function: %d", test)

func someChange(i interface{}) error{
    newFunnyValue := 42
    i = newFunnyValue
    fmt.Printf("hello from someChange now value test is: %d" , i)
    return nil //change gone ok, so nil
}
```

And result:

```
 hello from someChange now value test is: 42 
 after function: 0
```

I read that `interface{}` is similar to `void*` so above code should work but it's not, why? I want to add that if I pass some object which is a struct, everything works good.

Do I have to wrap `int` in some struct?

Edit:

https://play.golang.org/p/rg1vabug0P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to observe the change outside of the `someChange()` function (in the `test` variable), you must modify the *pointed* value (assign a new value to it). You're not doing that, you just assign a new value to the `i` parameter (which is a local variable inside `someChange()`).

You may obtain the `*int` pointer from the `i` interface variable using [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions), and then you can assign a new value to the pointed value.

Example:

```
func someChange(i interface{}) error {
    newFunnyValue := 42
    if p, ok := i.(*int); ok {
        *p = newFunnyValue
        return nil //change gone ok, so nil
    }
    return errors.New("Not *int")
}
```

Testing it:

```
var test int
someChange(&test)
log.Printf("after function: %d", test)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZCpkMYc57p)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 after function: 42
```

Note that wrapping the `int` value or the `*int` pointer in a struct is unnecessary and it wouldn't make a difference if you're not assigning a new value to the pointed object.

Comment: Yes. This is it. Thx, I did not think  that is necessary to use type assertion to this simply operation

Answer (score 1):

`i` is still of type `interface{}` within the `func someChange()`. You have to cast it during the assignment:

```
*i.(*int) = 42
```